# Height:0 and then slide down

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".logo").click(function() {
    $("#list").slideToggle(400);
   });
   $(window).resize(function() {
     if ($(window).width() < 767) {
      $("#list").slideUp(0);
     } else {
      $("#list").slideDown(0);
     }
   });
  });
```

```css
* {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

#wholeNav {
 height: 580px;
 top: 0;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);    /* BACKGROUND OPACITY */
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#wholeNav::after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
 background-image: url(background.jpg);     /* WHOLE BACKGROUND */
 height: 580px;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: -2;
}

 #wholeNav img[src="ham.png"] {
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
 }

 #navBar {
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
 }

  #list {
   float: right;
   width: 70%;
   position: relative;
   max-height: 100px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background-color: green;
  }

   #list li {
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 10%;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
   }
    li a {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: black;
    }

    a:hover {          /* COLOR LETTER WEB VERSION */
     color: yellow;
     transition: 0.2s;
    }

  #navBar img[src="logo.png"] {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
    
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 #wholeNav {
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 500px;
 }

 #wholeNav::after {
  height: 500px;
 }

  #wholeNav img[src="ham.png"] {
   display: block;
   height: 16px;
   width: 22px;
   padding: 14px 0;
   margin-left: 6%;
  }

  #navBar {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   height: 44px;
   margin-top: 0;
  }

   #list {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 218px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
   }

    #list li {
     display: block;
     float: none;
     width: 88%;
     border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
     font-size: 18px;
     margin-left: 6%;
     line-height: 40px;
     text-transform: none;
    }

    a:hover {          /* COLOR LETTER MOBILES VERSION */
     color: yellow;
     transition: 0.2s;
    }

    #navBar ul li:last-child {
     border-bottom: 0px solid green;
    }
```

```html
<div id="navBar">
   <img class="logo" src="ham.png">
   <img src="logo.png">
   <ul id="list">
    <li> <a href="#"> Kop1 </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Kop2 </a>  </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Kop3 </a>  </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Kop4 </a>  </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Kop5 </a>  </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

I'm working on a navigation bar. When I click on the .logo-class (a hamburger-icon), the menu has to slide down. `#list` is the menu. And when I press it again, the menu has to slide up. Therefore I use `slideToggle()`. When the page loads, the #list needs to have a height of 0. However now the function doesn't work. Is there a way to set the height to auto? I use resize() because my website has a mobile version and a web version.

When the page loads, the green section (#list) must not appear if the body.width is < 768px. This is the mobile version.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could post a working snippet showing the issue - or at the very least your HTML and CSS. The JS alone doesn't really help identify the problem.

Comment: is this what you are looking for ? https://jsfiddle.net/2mxo7zdq/1/

Comment: Yes, kind of. But the problem is that if you reload, you see the div for a few ms. A sort of flickering which isn't what I want.

Comment: `#wholeNav img[src="ham.png"]` yikes... `#wholeNav .logo` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the `style="display:none;"` for the list initially

here is the updates jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/2mxo7zdq/2/